# Creating the Liar's Paradox with one truth and one lie (that aren't meta).

Tags: logic, game-theory, paradoxes

Some friends were playing a game where you say 1 truth and 1 lie about yourself, and the others have to guess which is which.

Just for fun, I was wondering if there was a reasonable way to give 2 statements about myself (1 assumed to be truth, and the other a lie) that would generate a Liar's Paradox (i.e. assigning a truth value either way leads to a paradox).

Obviously, I could make the statements:
1.) Statement 2 is False.
2.) Statement 1 is True.
and that would cleanly get me the Liar's paradox, but each of those are "meta" statements (statements that explicitly refer to the other statement). But what I want are more "reasonable" statements (preferably that could be about myself) that would lead to such a paradox. Statements like "I own all 50 state coins", or "I've never eaten waffles", etc..

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no, although I could easily be mistaken.  First of all, I have never seen true/false paradoxes that were not caused by meta-statements.  Secondly, contradictions don't exist in nature.  So, if you make any assertion about yourself, or any other aspect of reality, I would surmise that either the assertion is actually true, or the assertion is actually false.  Having (for example) two such assertions lead to a paradox seems to suggest *reality contradicting itself*.

Comment: You could make the meta aspect a bit less prominent, e.g,, "I follow the rules of this game" and "It is easy to find out when I lie"

Answer (score 1):

Since realty is logically consistent (to the best of our knowledge), it is *not* possible to obtain truly paradoxical statements that are purely factual (without changing our fundamental understanding of the world). However, as you noted we can get such statements using meta references.

---

**However, it is still possible to satisfy the *intent* of your question.**

One solution can be to make factual statements about the kind of statements you make.

#### Example:

**Statement 1:** I have not told any lies in this game

**Statement 2:** I never speak the truth

The statements are fine by themselves if spoken from third person point of view  ("Person A hasn't told any lies in this game" and "Person A never speaks the truth" are individually non-paradoxical statements") but cause a paradox if spoken by the same person.

Assume that statement 1 is true. Then statement 2 is a lie since you have spoken a true statement.

If statement 2 is true, then it is again a contradiction.

The trick is to make meta statements without making explicit references to the statements ;)

Note that statement 2 is actually sufficient by itself here. It is equivalent to the famous self-contradictory statement "This sentence is false".

So, strictly you could say:

1. The Earth is a planet (Truth)
2. I never speak the truth (Lie)

Comment: You say "The statements are fine by themselves but [...]" and then later "Note that statement 2 is actually sufficient by itself [...]".  I'm not sure how to interpret both those statements.

Comment: @BrianMoehring That is very meta.

Comment: @MorganRodgers :-)  I never imagined the whole post might be the example and not just the labeled statements!